# Why doesn't swapping male to female as the reference category in earnings regression change the value not just the sign on the coefficient?

Tags: regression, logarithm, percentage

In an earnings regression (log linear, i.e. coefficient is an approximate % change), with gender why doesn't the coefficient value change (except the sign which obviously reverses) when you alternate between male and female as the base reference category? Gender pay gap % difference depends on the base used?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a minimal verifiable complete example as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Also consider that how much a percent is always depends on what the basis for your percents is.

Comment: So in Stata: reg lnSalaryMidpoint ib0.Female i.NACESector , base  and reg lnSalaryMidpoint ib1.Female  i.NACESector, base.....are giving me the same value on the gender coefficient, just different signs obviously, but since the base swaps from male to female, how can they be the same? Coefficient is  -.1182215  /  .1182215 depending on base

Comment: Can you please add that example (with outputs) to the post as an edit?

Comment: "Minimal" means an example that doesn't include a dozen or more irrelevant regressors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other two explanations for your problem.

1. When estimating models with dummies, there is a very close relationship between the "omitted/base" category, the controlled category, and the constant.

For example:

$$ y = a_0+a_1 * female + a_2 * X +e $$

So, given the above model, a women's $Y$ would be
$$ \hat{y}_{female}=a_0+a_1+a_2*X $$
If we estimate the model, the other way round we would have:
$$ y = b_0+b_1 * male + b_2 * X +e $$
and the wages for a woman will be:
$$ \hat{y}_{female}=b_0+b_2*X $$

From here you see that $b_2$ and $a_2$ must be the same. and that $b_0=a_0+b1$

So, changing the base category, only re-arranges where the coefficient's sign not magnitude.

Now for your interpretation. It does have an impact on how you will interpret it.

Wage change for men: $(exp(b_1)-1)*100 = 12.52 $

Wage change for women: $(exp(a_1)-1)*100 =-11.13 $

Men earn approximately 12.52% more than women, or women earn 11.13% less than men.
HTH

Answer (score 1):

Because, as you say, a log-difference only *approximates* percentage changes.

When something goes up by 10% and then down by 10%, you are not back at the original value. Log-differences are symmetric. See also [Are log difference time series models better than growth rates?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221780/are-log-difference-time-series-models-better-than-growth-rates/221809#221809).

This follows from Taylor-expanding the log as in
$$
\log(x)=\log(x_0)+\frac{1}{x_0}(x-x_0)+\text{Remainder}
$$
so that
$$
\log(x)-\log(x_0)\approx\frac{x-x_0}{x_0},
$$
where the approximation is good when $x$ and $x_0$ are close.

Illustration in R:

```
baseline <- 100
change <- 10
new.value <- baseline + change
(percentage.chg <- 100*((baseline + change)/baseline - 1))
(percentage.chg2 <- 100*((new.value + change)/new.value - 1))


(log.difference <- 100*(log(new.value) - log(baseline)))
(log.difference2 <- 100*(log(baseline) - log(new.value)))
```

Output:

```
> (percentage.chg <- 100*((baseline + change)/baseline - 1))
[1] 10

> (percentage.chg2 <- 100*((new.value + change)/new.value - 1))
[1] 9.090909

> (log.difference <- 100*(log(new.value) - log(baseline)))
[1] 9.531018

> (log.difference2 <- 100*(log(baseline) - log(new.value)))
[1] -9.531018
```

Graphically, the approximation looks as follows. The dark green curve is the log-function, the light green the Taylor approximation $\log(x_0)+(x-x_0)/x_0$ so that the red bar is the approximation error at the new value `x_n`:

[image]

Code:

```
x_0 <- 0.9
x_n <- 1.2

x <- seq(0.6, 1.3, by=.01)

plot(x, log(x), type="l", lwd=2, col="darkgreen", ylab="", cex.axis=.9)
segments(x_0, -0.6, x_0, log(x_0), lty=2)
segments(x_0, log(x_0), 0.5, log(x_0), lty=2)
segments(x_n, -0.6, x_n, log(x_n), lty=2)
segments(x_n, log(x_n), 0.5, log(x_n), lty=2)
lines(x, log(x_0) + 1/x_0*(x-x_0), lty=1, lwd=2, col="lightgreen")

segments(x_n, log(x_n), x_n, log(x_0) + (x_n-x_0)/x_0, lty=1, col="red", lwd=3)
segments(x_n, log(x_0) + (x_n-x_0)/x_0, 0.5, log(x_0) + (x_n-x_0)/x_0, lty=2)

segments(0.6, log(x_0), 0.6, log(x_n), lty=1, col="brown", lwd = 3)
text(0.61, 0, "log(x_n) - log(x_0)", col="brown", adj = 0, cex=.9, font=2)

segments(0.8, log(x_0), 0.8, log(x_0) + (x_n-x_0)/x_0, lty=1, col="orange", lwd = 3)
text(0.81, 0, "(x_n-x_0)/x_0", col="orange", adj = 0, cex=.9, font=2)

text(0.91, -0.52, "x_0", adj = 0, cex=.9)
text(1.21, -0.52, "x_n", adj = 0, cex=.9)
text(0.5, log(x_0), "log(x_0)", adj = 0, xpd=T, cex=.9)
text(0.5, log(x_n), "log(x_n)", adj = 0, xpd=T, cex=.9)
text(0.58, log(x_0) + (x_n-x_0)/x_0+.02, "log(x_0) + (x_n-x_0)/x_0", adj = 0, xpd=T, cex=.9)

text(0.65, -0.45, "log(x)", col="darkgreen", adj = 0, cex=.9, font=2)
text(0.58, -0.25, "log(x_0) + 1/x_0*(x-x_0)", col="lightgreen", adj = 0, cex=.9, font=2)
```