# If 1% increase in X = .28% decrease in Y, does a 1% decrease in X = a .28% increase in Y?

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, elasticity

I performed a log-log regression and have a negative regression coefficient. I'm interpreting my results to indicate that a 1% increase in X is associated with a .28% decrease in Y. However, for visualization purposes, it would make more sense to show a graph of potential Y values as X *decreases*. First, I thought I would just reverse it to say that a 1% decrease in X is associated with a .28% increase in Y, but the more I think about it, I'm not sure if this is necessarily true.

Would greatly appreciate it if anyone can tell me if my interpretation of the relationship in the reverse is correct and if not, how can I calculate the % change in Y associated with a 1% decrease in X? Thanks so much!

Comment: I find this to be a worthwhile explanation: https://youtu.be/NZCSt9WkpkI

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513002/why-doesnt-swapping-male-to-female-as-the-reference-category-in-earnings-regres/513016#513016